# Using custom routes instead of /controller/action/{id}

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have to make vanity urls for an already existing site. The requirements are:

- The existing controllers are a kind of hierarchical structure and can't go away or be overridden in any way. Examples: *domain.com/Dog/vanity* and *domain.com/Cat/vanity*.
- Keep existing actions. Any existing actions must take priority so that the page for that action is not stomped on by the vanity url.
- take future pages and actions into account so that the above requirement is met (a new vanity url is ignored and the action/view executed instead)

To date, I have tried various solutions with routing that allow me to have *domain.com/vanity* which is nice but the marketing guys don't like because of the different departments within the company. I've tried routing which will override the existing actions and treats them all as vanities (also not feasible). I've a solution in place that programmatically deals with the url that was requested and redirects to a page that actually exists but this is not scalable in any way.

So far, I know that the vanity portion can be treated as a parameter to the action so that I can fire off the default page in the route (Index) but this is, so far, doesn't preserve the structure.

TL;DR: I need to have a solution that allows for domain/controller/vanity structure while also allowing domain/controller/action

Comment: Tried http://attributerouting.net/?

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't heard about it. I'm looking at it right now. The less that I have to add to the site project, the better (it's getting replaced in a few months but marketing people want this now.)

I don't suppose you have a one sentence TL;DR of this plugin?

Comment: Basically (after configuration), you add `[Route("an-area-or-string/some-action-or-string")]` to your actions and call www.example.com/an-area-or-string/some-action-or-string to access that action.

Comment: Thanks again! This sounds worth checking out. I'll post if this does what I need. Even if it does, the less that I have to do to this inherited project, the better. It's a hacked up mess; I'm certain that if I change too much in it that the world will end.

Comment: Attribute routing seems to be what you want, then. It's a minimum impact effort, in my opinion. You can even have more than one Route attribute per action. You can also work with route prefixes on controllers.

Comment: Saweet! This is almost exactly what I was looking for. I don't like that I have to have an action for each vanity url but this is good enough to use if I can't get a routing solution.

Comment: Well, if multiple vanity-urls point to same actions (just with different parameters), then simply put all those Route attributes on that action. Maybe I don't understand that particular detail of your problem, but glad you found something that'll work in the meantime.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying I could say 
   [Route("Home/Stuff")]
   [Route("Home/Cat")]
   [Route("Home/Dog")]
        public ActionResult Index(string campaign)
        {
           ...
        }//end Stuff vanity URL


Instead of having an action for each?

Edit: No, what you're saying is that I can have:

     [Route("Home/Dog")]
        [Route("Home/Cat")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return CollectTrackingData();
        }//end index

Instead of lots of junks code. Way cool.

Comment: Instead of saying "Solved" you should just delete the question.

Comment: Okay, can do. But before I do, what if someone has the exact same question next week?

Comment: ASP.NET WebApi have official support for attribute routing (without a third party package)

Comment: Wait, what? Convince you to give me a url or google terms to find it myself?

Comment: @J.Steen: Provide an answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [AttributeRouting for MVC4](http://attributerouting.net/) you can accomplish a working solution until you ramp up the replacement project. It'll allow you to keep existing routes while adding new, custom ones with little impact.

```
[Route("my-vanity/is-cool/post/{id}")]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
}
```

The important part is to remember priority, so you write routes that don't overwrite/are overwritten by existing routes. You can steer this to some degree with properties on the attribute. Below is just an example that will put the added route last in priority for the entire site.

```
[Route("my-vanity/is-cool", SitePrecedence = -1)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

Comment: here is a +1 for that :)

Comment: @jgauffin Cheers. I had forgotten that WebApi2 had it built in, but since it uses the same base libraries as MVC 5, it's not surprising. :)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET WebApi2 have built in support for attribute routing. With it you can define URL's in whatever way you like (instead of following the `/controller/action` pattern)

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: I'm going to mark this as an answer even though it's not exactly what I need. This would be the technically correct answer but the attributerouting.net comment gives me the exact solution I need for this case: handle specific vanity urls with minimal coding and logic changes (the site is a hacked up mess and going away in several months) as well as the ability to assign the rerouting to any action for tracking purposes with no fuss.

This will, however, be the solution in the replacement site we're ramping up to start.

Comment: Then ask @J.Steen to provide an answer and accept that one.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix: Steen has added an answer, accept that one instead since it's what worked for you.

Comment: To add to jgauffin's answer about using modern libraries: ASP.NET MVC 5 has attribute-based routing built into it as well. =)

Comment: And done! 

We're still using MVC 4 but I'll see about us moving to 5 in the near future for just this reason (since our whole company is going to want this as soon as it starts working with this solution)